# Derivation for affine connection formulas on differentiable manifolds (General tensors)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

Let $p\in U\subseteq M$ be a point in some neighborhood of a finite-dimensional differentiable  manifold, $\{x^i\}$ a set of local coordinates with respect to $U$, and $\{e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}\}$ a set of basis vectors for $T_pM$.

Starting from a $(1,0)$ differentiable tensor field $X$ defined on $M$, I well understand that the affine connection with respect to $V\in T_pM$ is (Using the Einstein summation convention):

$$(*)\space \nabla_VX=V^i(\frac{\partial{X^j}}{\partial{x^i}}+X^k\Gamma^j_{ik})e_j.$$
Now if $\omega$ is a $(0,1)$ differentiable tesnor field on $M$, how does one derive $\nabla_V\omega$  from $(*)$?

Following the above, given $S$ is a $(p,q)$ differentiable tensor field on $M$, how does one derive $\nabla_VS$?

A reference to relevant material would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to do the all the computations but I'll tell you how to proceed:

To derive the expression of the covariant derivative on $(0,1)$-tensor fields aka one-forms (in other words to compute the induced connection on the dual bundle), use the identity

$$\nabla_V (\omega(X)) = (\nabla_V \omega)(X) + \omega(\nabla_V X)$$

where the left-hand side $\nabla_V (\omega(X))$ is just $V \cdot (\omega(X))$ by definition. So this tells you how to compute $(\nabla_V \omega)(X)$, which is what you're interested in.

To derive the expression of the covariant derivative on $(p,q)$-tensor fields (in other words to compute the induced connection on some tensor product of the tangent bundle and its dual), use the identity

$$ \nabla_V (\alpha \otimes \beta) = (\nabla_V\alpha) \otimes \beta + \alpha \otimes (\nabla_V \beta)$$

NB:  These identities are a natural extension of the Leibniz rule (and they are really the reason why -or the explanation how- the covariant derivative extends to tensor fields). You'll find them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Covector_fields) for instance.

Comment: Took me a few minutes to process and digest your answer, and consequently to see that it is complete and correct. Thank you for spelling out for me what I already ""knew"".. :)

Comment: Very welcome :)